# Kotlin - Optional Generic response in Ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

I have the following model for an api response:

```
@Serializable
public data class Response<out T>(
    val code: String,
    val message: String,
    val data: T? = null,
)
```

The thing is that the `data` field is optional. Therefore when I receive the full, it works fine. Full response being something like this:

```
{
"code":"code-sample",
"message":"This is a sample message",
"data": { ... }
}
```

**BUT** if I receive a body like this:

```
{
"code":"code-sample",
"message":"This is a sample message"
}
```

I receive the follwoing error message:

```
Captured type parameter T from generic non-reified function. Such functionality cannot be supported because T is erased, either specify serializer explicitly or make calling function inline with reified T.
```

So, how can I have a model that can be read with an optional generic like this?
My `Json` configuration is as such:

```
Json {
  ignoreUnknownKeys = true
  encodeDefaults = true
}
```

Comment: I've tested your setup and it works without a problem. Can you share the code snippet where the request is made?